# The multi-part identifier could not be bound in merge

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-merge

I am using below merge and getting "The multi-part identifier "MasterSource.monthvrip" could not be bound" error. Checked a lot in internet but no luck . Looks like using some defined keyword but not able to figure out. Any suggestion will be helpful.

```sql
USE TestDatabase

MERGE [dbo].[cost1] AS target   
USING (     
  SELECT [monthvrip]
  FROM [dbo].[cost]
) AS MasterSource
ON (MasterSource.[monthvrip] = target.[monthvrip])

WHEN MATCHED AND (MasterSource.[monthvrip] <> target.[monthvrip])
THEN UPDATE 
  SET MasterSource.[monthvrip] = target.[monthvrip]

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY target THEN 
INSERT 
  ([monthvrip])
VALUES 
  (MasterSource.[monthvrip])

OUTPUT
$action,
inserted.*,
deleted.*;
```

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>
> The multi-part identifier "MasterSource.monthvrip" could not be bound.

Comment: Are you sure this is the right syntax? [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Why not remove the "derived table" MasterSource since you're not doing any filtering in it, just selecting one column. In the end, just go with `MERGE cost1 as target USING cost as masterSource on masterSource.monthvrip = target.monthvrip`

Comment: Thanks. I have lot of columns in table and pasted here 1 so that code can be scanned easily.

Comment: Please consult the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), you cannot use an alias against the column to update. So use `SET [monthvrip] = `

Answer (score 3):

You need to change

```
THEN UPDATE 
  SET MasterSource.[monthvrip] = target.[monthvrip]
```

to

```
THEN UPDATE 
  SET target.[monthvrip] = MasterSource.[monthvrip]
```

The way you have it at the moment, you're trying to update the source of the merge, rather than the target.